# What happens with a diode and a battery in this circuit?

Tags: batteries, diodes

What would happen if I have a battery and a diode in a circuit with the diode trying to force the negative part of the battery to the positive part? Just wondering...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOFSDQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And we wonder what circuit you're blabbing about. There's a button to draw a nice circuit, use it ! No circuit means no answer.

Comment: As pointed out in the first comment a drawing of the schmatic will make it clear what you are asking. Without one we would just be guessing.

Comment: The diode cant 'force' current, it kinda 'permits' current. In the same way, if you 'permit' water to flow from the ground to your table by having a unidirectional valve pointing up, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have a somewhat fuzzy-worded short circuit. Depending on the exact realization,

- if you put the diode in the direction shown in your picture, it will *not* conduct, and nothing will happen.

Earlier answers (before you included the circuit):

- if you have a battery with a voltage lower than the voltage at which the diode starts conduction very little would happen
- the diode could explode, or fail less spectacularly, probably open
- some wire could melt
- the battery could start to boil, leak, explode, or just fail
- a moderate current could flow, limited by the resistances in the circuit, until the battery is empty

If you are referreing to an ideal battery and diode: you would have created a circuit that violates the requirements for being analyzable.

Comment: Why do we encourage these types of questions? No research, no effort whatsoever.

Comment: It is not a homwork question, more like someone wandering about something he doesn't even know the serach words for. And I ned an occasional humorous break from the daily routine...